# Google authentication gives an error when using localhost on chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, google-chrome, authentication

When I try to authenticated the user using Google accounts on chrome it throws the following error:

> This browser or app may not be secure

This was working before, I am not sure why it has suddenly stopped working.

I tried it on Firefox and it works completely fine, it is just an issue on chrome. I have reinstalled chrome and turned on allow less secure apps. Is there a reason this is happening?

Google authentication works fine on chrome when I am not using localhost.

Comment: Hello! I've gotten the same issue. Could you please explain what you mean under "when I am not using localhost"? Thank you

Comment: When I use Google Chrome normally, The authentication works fine and I do not get that message. When I run my application from visual studio, on Chrome I get that error. @creaturek